# Airflow: Task Not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I have a basic DAG setup with a python callable. The code inside the callable works fine and prints the log statement as well. It returns a list as expected.

```
with DAG(
...
        catchup=False
) as dag:

    def get_delta_lean_articles(**kwargs):
        
        logging.info(f"Total : {len(article_list)}")

        return article_list

   
    start = snowsql_operator.StepOperator(
        task_id='start'
    )

    get_lean_ids = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='lean_article_ids',
        python_callable=get_delta_lean_articles
    )

    end = snowsql_operator.StepOperator(
        task_id='end'
    )

    start >> get_lean_ids >> end
```

However, after returning the list, it gives me this error:

```
[2022-10-12 14:58:10,994] {python_operator.py:114} INFO - Done. Returned value was: ['63456df263', '6346d56', '6346']
[2022-10-12 14:58:10,995] {skipmixin.py:122} INFO - Following branch ['63456df263',....
[2022-10-12 14:58:11,033] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - Task 344885cd7836c6b9a924adddt not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 142, in execute
    self.skip_all_except(context['ti'], branch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/skipmixin.py", line 148, in skip_all_except
    dag.get_task(branch_task_id).get_flat_relative_ids(upstream=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1263, in get_task
    raise TaskNotFound("Task {task_id} not found".format(task_id=task_id))
airflow.exceptions.TaskNotFound: Task 344885cd7836c6b9a924adddt not found
```

When I check the UI, the BranchPythonOperator has already failed and is red.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using BatchPythonOperator instead of PythonOperator.